# Can you update firestore query dynamically based on router location?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-router

So basically, I have a simple React app connected to Firebase that lists different types of food from firestore collections.

Example:

- I have a few categories. The default one is "All" that displays top 8 popular dishes from all other available categories and this part is easy but I want an user to be able to click on other category and update my query.

Category is actually a NavLink that updates location on click so: 
 
 if user click on "Pizza" category the url looks like this localhost:3000/Pizza 
 if he clicks on Salad it is localhost:3000/Salad etc. 

I have a "Wall" component that is a section and it displays those items from firestore.

My query ref in this wall component look like this: 
`const foodRef = db.collection("food").doc("all").collection("items");`

But I want to set .doc dynamically and make query on every update so I changed the query to something like that:

```
const location = useLocation();
const foodRef = db.collection("food").doc('${location.pathname}').collection("items");
```

And when user click on different Card (NavLink) url updates but query does not.

I know it is a bad solution but I actually have no idea how to do that. 
I have read about Recursive Paths in react router but I do not know if it is what I am looking for. 
If you know how to approach that please let me know.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore does not support wildcards or replacements in queries and Query objects are fully immutable (they can't be changed).  You have to know the names of the documents and collections ahead of time to build a query.  If you want to change some part of a query, you have to rebuild a whole new query object every time, and run the query again to get a new set results.